# AngularFire: get single object from Observable array without querying the database again

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs

I have two components that share a service. One of the components gets an entire collection from Firestore as an observable.

The second component should display all the data for a single document.
However, I am not sure how I can achieve this without querying the database again.

I have tried using `pipe(map(documents => documents.find(...matching logic...)))` on the existing observable, but it still queries the database again.

So TL;DR: I query an entire collection, how can I get a single document from that without querying the database again?

Comment: Cache the "entire collection" response in the service (possibly using an observable). Use the cached data in the second component.

Comment: Pipe `shareReplay(1)`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: @NielsKersic please add the solution as an answer so others can see that the question is solved, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By piping in `shareReplay(1)` when first retrieving the collection, subsequent requests will use a locally cached collection instead of requesting the data from the database again.

The first request will look something like this

```
this.angularFirestore.collection('collection')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe( shareReplay(1) )
```